# Can't play file from documents in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift2, avaudioplayer, nsfilemanager

I have a file on documents folder of app and I want to play it.

```
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(pathString) {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:pathString, isDirectory: false)
    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url)
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    }
    catch let error as NSException {
        print(error)
    }
    catch {}
}
```

There is a file on file system and I checked its existence. Also all lines in do block are executed. There is neither exception nor error and still no sound is played. What are possible problems and how can I solve them?

Comment: The only problem with code was audioPlayer which should be set globally!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should make audioPlayer an instance variable global. This code will have it deallocated immediately after calling .play()

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(pathString){
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:pathString, isDirectory: false)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not working yet! Do you have any idea how to understand what problem is? Or how to debug it?

Comment: Are you certain you changed audioPlayer to be global? It should work like this...

Comment: BTW, you'll have to learn and understand local and global variables, and memory management in Swift... Good luck!

Comment: In this snippet, aren't you creating the audio player twice? Once at view instantiation and a 2nd time when the view calls viewDidLoad. If so,  how would you do this so that it is instantiated just once?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar try writing    `var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!` instead of 
   `'var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()`